# R - How to give a same name to every element of vector?

Tags: r, vector, sapply

Is it possible to assign a same name to each element of vector in R?
For example, I have a vector `a <- c(1:10)` and I want to give each element name `"A"`.

I would like to end up with something like this:

```
A A A A A A A A A A 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
names(a) <- c(rep("A", 10))
```

Comment: Don't need the `c()`.

Comment: @RichardScriven Okay, thanks. In that case `a = 1:10; for (bah in 1:2) names(a)[] <- "A"` :)

Comment: You could do `names(a) <- "A"[a-a+1]`